# How to integrate my initial class (Google Maps View) in further view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that contains the Google Maps MapView that has several features (drawing polygon, drawing marker etc). I added some UI elements on the initial view controller and now I want the further view controllers to inherit this Google Maps MapView (right now when the user clicks on those elements, you are just taken to a blank new screen with further UI elements - but the initial functionality, the MapView, is missing). How do I do this?

Comment: So the map never changes the position in the screen?

Comment: No the map remains fixed as the background.

Comment: You can put a container view in the place that will change and every push you make you make inside the container view so the map outside the container view is going to be fixed

Comment: How do you mean? http://imgur.com/a/55BAr

Comment: @konyv12 you need to add new viewcontrol before mapview?

Comment: But now changes that I make to the map are not shown in further view controllers?

Comment: Try creating your UI Elements as an xib file and just re-using the view on each viewController. Or user the same viewController and just create an overlay.